# Get native HTML element in Cypress

Tags: javascript, dom, cypress

How do I get an underlying native `HTMLElement` (or `Element` or `Node`...) from a Cypress query?

```js
const el = cy.get('.foo').children().first()
//    ^ this is of type Cypress.Chainable<JQuery<HTMLElement>>
```

I would like to access the native `HTMLElement` instance in `el`.
I have tried `el[0]` but the result is of type `any`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In cypress, `first()` is a command that will be chained to `.get()` and retry for that whole selection until timeout. That is why you can't really obtain the native element from it.

You can however yield the command, and access the element inside `.then()`  by passing a function to it.

For example, from the [Cypress documentation on this EXACT question](https://docs.cypress.io/faq/questions/using-cypress-faq.html#How-do-I-get-the-native-DOM-reference-of-an-element-found-using-Cypress):

```
cy.get('.foo').then(($el) => {
  const el = $el.get(0) //native DOM element
})
```

Comment: Thank you, I should have found that via search 

Comment: As of may 2022, this no longer works with Cypress 9.6.1. Ideas?

Comment: @thednp, according to the documentation, nothing changed

Comment: Actually it's working for me, in 2023; +1 mate.