# How to get Cypress element from native DOM element?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cypress, cypress-each

```
Cypress.Commands.add('clearScheduleEditor', () => {
    cy.get(getBySelector("schedule-editor")).find(".fc-event").should(() => {
    }).then($events => {
        if ($events.length) {
            Cypress._.each($events, (event) => {
                console.log(event)

            })
        }
    })
})
```

Here i have my code sample where im trying to delete all ever existed events. Thats why i need to .each them to open every single one to delete. But the problem is that .each func returns me as a value of callback (event) the Dom element, but i need an cypress element

I need to do reversed operation to this [Get native HTML element in Cypress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58879901/get-native-html-element-in-cypress)

Need to get Cypress element

Answer (score 4):

The error is the deleting action causes a redraw of the page, so you cannot use `.each()`.

`.each()` takes a reference to the elements, but the redraw changes the elements and so `.each()` fails.

Use a for-loop instead.

```js
cy.get(selector).then($els => {
  const count = $els.length
  for (let index = 0; index < count; index++) {
    cy.get(selector)
      .eq(index)
      .then($el => $el[0].remove())
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You would be needing ***[`Cypress.$()`](https://docs.cypress.io/api/utilities/$)*** to wrap the DOM element into a [JQuery](http://jquery.com/) object, post which you can use ***[`cy.wrap()`](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/wrap)*** to convert it into a Cypress object to perform `click` or other actions required to delete the event. A sample of the above looks like:

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('clearScheduleEditor', () => {
    cy.get(getBySelector("schedule-editor")).find(".fc-event").should(() => {
    }).then($events => {
        if ($events.length) {
            Cypress._.each($events, (event, idx) => {
                console.log(event);
                // const $event = Cypress.$(event);
                // cy.wrap($event).click();
                cy.get(getBySelector("schedule-editor")).find(".fc-event").eq(idx).click();
                // Add any other actions required to delete the event
            });
        }
    });
});
```

##### EDIT:

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('clearScheduleEditor', () => {
    cy.get(getBySelector("schedule-editor")).find(".fc-event").should(() => {
    }).then($events => {
        if ($events.length) {
            cy.get(getBySelector("schedule-editor")).find(".fc-event").then(($events) => {
                // Keep clicking and deleting the first event until no events are left
                while ($events.length > 0) {
                    cy.get(getBySelector("schedule-editor")).find(".fc-event").first().click();
                    // Add any other actions required to delete the event

                    // Recheck the events and update the $events variable
                    cy.get(getBySelector("schedule-editor")).find(".fc-event").then(($newEvents) => {
                        $events = $newEvents;
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: but the problem is that i cannot use chaining here because of this error: cy.click() failed because the page updated as a result of this command, but you tried to continue the command chain. The subject is no longer attached to the DOM, and Cypress cannot requery the page after commands such as cy.click().

Comment: @Taras When you try to click on the event and the page updates, Cypress loses the reference to the element. THis is the reason you're getting the error. Check the updted code and let me know. I will update my answer and explanation if it works. But usually that would do

Comment: Now reference works but when it deletes half of events, the other half gets their indexes (like from 0 again), but the variable idx still counts them using previous indexes

Comment: @Taras This is a simple edge case which you can take care of. Let me update the code.

Comment: @Taras try the edited code now.